# Og:description meta tag for slack app link unfurling

Tags: javascript, html, slack

Is og:description or twitter:description tag necessary for slack to unfurl html page's link contents ?

I have a link with og:title , type , url , image and description tags . Slack app unfurls the link fine . But when I remove the description tag or if set the content of description tag null , then nothing is unfurled .

Ideally besides description other things should have been previewed in slack .
How is title and image and other things dependent on description tag ?

Answer (score 3):

Slack displays og:description tag, not twitter:description.
Title and image don't anymore depend on description tag.
Even when og:description is null, removed or spacefilled Slack generates social snippet.

In case description is not provided Slack is able to display a title up to 2000 symbols.

Slack uses a combination of Open Graph and Twitter tags to unfurl links as shown in [Slack API Documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/link-unfurling#classic_unfurl)

For generating purposes [Website Open Graph Generator](https://webcode.tools/generators/open-graph/website) is useful.
For validating [FB Sharing debugging](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is handy.